# How to override scrolling of the main window with one page website plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, scroll

```
<div class="scrollable">
   some data here.......
</div>
```

I want to scroll a div within a one page website, however. Even with the following css properties, the plugin to make the one page website takes preference.

The div content does begin to scroll, however, the page is changed.

CSS

```
.cvContent{
margin: 0 auto;
height: 80%;
width: 80%;
overflow: scroll;
padding: 8px;
}
```

any help would be great!

Comment: What plugin is overriding the scroll event? You could try adding 'overflow: important!" to your CSS to see if you can get that rule to take preference, although it sounds like the plugin is using JS to override your scroll event.

Comment: Im using the plugin provided by this website, 
[plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html)I was wondering whether inside the js plugin, I could do an if statement which would allow me to avoid the scrolling for main window for the specific div..